# Por que minha classe não aplica o estilo que defini para a tag "h1"?

Tags: html, css

Fiz um exemplo de um código em CSS para aprender um pouco mais a fundo sobre o uso de classes. No entanto, eu percebi um erro e não consigo compreender bem o motivo.

### 1° exemplo

```css
.fonte-style-h1 {
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 30%;
 color: yellow;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CSS</title> 
</head>
<body> 
 <h1 class=".fonte-style-h1">Oie CSS!</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

Perceba neste exemplo eu criei a classe `.fonte-style-h1` para definir um estilo para o conteúdo da tag `h1` e veja que não houve efeito algum.

### 2° exemplo

```css
h1 {
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 250%;
 color: seagreen;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CSS</title> 
</head>
<body> 
 <h1>Oie CSS!</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```

Neste segundo exemplo veja que eu apliquei o estilo para a tag `h1` de uma forma geral e funcionou. É neste ponto que surge minha dúvida.

---

## Pergunta

Por que a classe `.fonte-style-h1` não aplica o estilo para tag `h1` e quando uso `h1` ao invés da classe funciona?

Comment: Uma dica é que o mesmo que se aplica para o ID, onde no .CSS ficaria `#nome-do-id {estilos}` e no HTML vc teria `<elemento id="nome-do-id">` então `id="#nome-do-id"` também estaria errado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você está usando `.` antes do nome da sua class:

```
<h1 class=".fonte-style-h1">Oie CSS!</h1>
```

Tente usar sem o ponto dessa forma:

```
<h1 class="fonte-style-h1">Oie CSS!</h1>
```

O ponto é só a referência que você usa no `css`, na class você utiliza apenas o nome.No entanto que exsiste o `.` para definir uma `class` e a `#` para definir um `id`.

Só funcionou da outra forma, porque você atribui direto ao h1 que por sua vez já é reservado, e não precisaria de `.` nem `#`

Comment: Não havia percebido que tinha que remover o ponto ;)

Answer (score 8):

O correto é `<h1 class="fonte-style-h1">Oie CSS!</h1>` no atributo `class` nao precisamos colocar o ponto igual no arquivo css.

Você so precisa retirar o ponto de `<h1 class=".fonte-style-h1">Oie CSS!</h1>`

```css
.fonte-style-h1 {
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-size: 30%;
 color: yellow;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>CSS</title> 
</head>
<body> 
 <h1 class="fonte-style-h1">Oie CSS!</h1> 
</body>
</html>
```